# Media import failed in the WordPress importer

Tags: uploads, media-library, migration

I've just merged two WordPress sites into one (on my local dev. machine). I used the standard Export / Import tool.

I made export files from both sites, imported them into my dev. machine. I selected to download media files. It said that all media files from one site failed to import. I copied all the media files (1 folder, 1500 images) from that site to my dev machines upload folder. I did some find and replace and the images showed perfectly.

I was really happy :) Until...

I realised that the images (will display fine but they) are not included in the media library. They only exist as links to images in a folder.

Are there any way to import those images to the media library later?

Answer (score 0):

I found a plugin called [Add from server](https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-from-server/) that I used to pull in the images.

It doesn't feel rock solid but I think it worked.